# How Do I Use Armatures , I cannot get them to work with my meshes

Tags: rendering, animation, texturing, game-engine, armature

Im Trying To Learn How To Animate Movement with Armatures but all i can seem to do is move the armatures and not the actual mesh.

Comment: Did you assign weights to the mesh, linked to the bones? Or maybe you are in Edit Mode?

Comment: i am clueless on how to do this perhaps if you gave me some step by step instructions on how to use them.

Comment: Are the bones already connected to each other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to parent the mesh to the armature with Automatic Weights, and then adjust the weights later on:

- Select the mesh (Object Mode), and then select the armature
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, and then select 'Automatic weights'. Now Blender assigned weights to the mesh and parented them to the bones of the armature, depending on how the bones and mesh are relatively located.

To modify the weights:

- You could select the armature and enter 'pose mode', by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Then you select the mesh and enter 'Weight paint mode', by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd>. Now you can select a bone, while you can edit the weight paints of the mesh using the brush